# simulation/ probabilty

Tags: probability, random, simulation

Suppose a population control plan for the country of Transylvania allows parents to have at most four children each,
      and they must stop having children when they get two girls.  Explain how to use a random number generator to 
      simulate the experiment of having children until you have either two girls or four children.  Describe what you’ll put
      in your calculator, what the digits represent, and when you’ll know when one trial is complete.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Sounds like a good homework problem...what are your thoughts on it?

Comment: not to be rude but idk , thats why I asked

Comment: You don't know what you've tried, or you don't know what your thoughts on it are?